# JQuery Validation - Disable onfocusout for one field only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to ignore "onfocusout" property for one form field out of 5 using Jquery validation plugin?

I mean, Jquery validation plugin currently validates an element onblur of that form field. I would like the plugin to not do so for one form field only. It can keep that validation for other form fields.

How can I do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15):

You can override `onfocusout` event handler in the options you pass to the `.validate()` method. The overriden version should which element is being handled, falling back to the default behaviour if it is not the field you want to exclude:

```
$('#test').validate({
    rules: {
        "field1": "required",
        "field2": "required",
        "field3": "required"
    },
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
        if (element.name !== "field2") {
            $.validator.defaults.onfocusout.call(this, element, event);
        }
    }
});
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZwqL/) for full demo.

Comment: Thanks, @Infeligo. In my case I had to put the above code outside of the document load handler, toward the top of my JS on the page, otherwise it didn't have any effect.